# NodeJS upload files

Tags: node.js, http-post, next.js, fs, fetch-api

I'm trying to implement a file uploading feature. I have watched and read many tutorials, but all of them require one or another library like `multer`, `formidable`, `axios` or something else. As far as I learnt, it can be done without any external library, so it is how I want it - with minimal to none additional libraries.

On frontend I pack the file into `FormData` and send it via `fetch`:

```
if (file) {
    const fd = new FormData()
    fd.append('file', file)
    const res = await fetch('/api/files', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: fd
    })
}
```

On backend the body of request looks like this:

```
-----------------------------26088851433443883591868954602
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="1.png"
Content-Type: image/png

�PNG
→
IHDR�♦☻g�V¶☺sRGB��∟�♦gAMA��♂�a♣ pHYs♫�♫�☺�o�d{�IDATx^��⌂��W}▼����č↔;��6�4�6m��Lg�5�;q�&D�ۦ�8Nm�4����n�
-----------------------------312671409112038349881281368983--
```

I tried so far:

- sending `file` without packing it into `FormData` does not change anything
- `fs.writeFile()` gives a file with about right size, but it is not valid file
- `fs.writeFile()` with `base64` option gives a file with only one line inside it
- `req.files.mv()` which worked in tutorial with `axios` cannot read `files` and fails
- `req.body.mv()` also fails with `mv is not a function`

What can I do about it to make it working? If it helps somehow, my project is written in NextJS.

Comment: There must be file/files section in the req.headers if you send file through xhr post request.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik there is only one thing in headers that counts into file sending. It looks like this: 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------311666031135710179444280276599'